# Problem with a usb pendrive

Tags: usb

One pendrive is not mounting. In disks or gparted the pendrive does not appear. When i run dmesg, the pendrive appears but:

```
[852423.710577] sdd: detected capacity change from 30031872 to 0
[852427.158731] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 4
```

The pendrive contains important information. Any possible solution?

Thanks and sorry for my english!

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if you are lucky, find a solution.

Comment: If your drive appears as a mass storage device `/dev/sdx` but the file system is corrupted, you can try to repair it, and if that does not work, you can try to recover the file data with [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec). - But if your drive does not appear as a mass storage device I don't know any tool that can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think the pendrive is dead